# Search in not working for the field

Tags: grails

I have three fields in my domain class i.e client_id ,client_name,client_address. I want to do search on the basic of client_name in the list.gsp page. I tried it but not working for me. I'm new to grails. Do m'i following the right approach or any possible solutions?

list.gsp page :-

```
    <g:if test="${flash.message}">
            <div class="message" role="status">${flash.message}</div>
        </g:if>
        <fieldset class="form">
            <g:form action="list" method="GET">
                <div class="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="query">Search for Client Name:</label>
                    <g:textField name="query" value="${params.query}"/>
                </div>
            </g:form>
        </fieldset>
```

ClientController.groovy :-

```
  def list(Integer max) {
    params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)


    def taskList = Client.createCriteria().list (params) {
        if ( params.query ) {
            ilike("client_name", "%${params.query}%")
            ilike("client_id", "%${params.query}%")
        }
    }

    [clientInstanceList: taskList, clientInstanceTotal: Client.count()]
}
```

Comment: Little Bird  try to remove `value="${params.query}"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whit your code Grails will generate query like following

where lower(this_.client_name) like ? **and** lower(this_.client_id) like ? )

I guess you need to change it to **OR** conduction.

```
 def taskList = Client.createCriteria().list (params) {
        if ( params.query ) {
             or{
                ilike("client_name", "%${params.query}%")
                ilike("client_id", "%${params.query}%")
               }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Grails Rich-UI Plugin.In that plugin Auto Complete option is available.....